# What does the [] mean in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1] asp.net trace message and how to find the corresponding code location?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to troubleshoot ASP.NET Core v2.1 issue and seeing the following statement in the trace log where I suspect my issue is happening:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
```

What does the `[]` mean in this context and how do I find the code location that corresponds the `[1]` inside the `WebHost.cs`?

There are many more of these kid of trace messages in the log like:

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[4]
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter[1]
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **Log Event ID**, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#log-event-id).

It is helpful to quickly identify related logs, especially when you are logging custom messages. It is just a simple integer so it is worth defining a `static class` with a list of integer constants so that you can then reuse the same ID on multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

[Log event ID](http://Log%20event%20ID)

> An event ID associates a set of events. For example, all logs related
>   to displaying a list of items on a page might be 1001.
>
> The logging provider may store the event ID in an ID field, in the
>   logging message, or not at all. The Debug provider doesn't show event
>   IDs. The console provider shows event IDs in brackets after the
>   category:

```
info: TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController[1002]
      Getting item invalidid
warn: TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController[4000]
      GetById(invalidid) NOT FOUND
```

I belive you can only get stack trace information with line number with exception, though i may be wrong